# get scroll event in javascript with full height page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that is set to `height: 100vh`
Now I want a function to be triggered when the user tries to scroll. onScroll doesn't work since it is impossible to scroll. How can I still get the onscroll event?

If it is any helpful, here is the pen
https://codepen.io/Sinanski/pen/wEbeMo?editors=0110

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event might help you - although this won't trigger on scroll events from the keyboard. So you might put together something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", onScroll);

window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);

function onScroll(event) {
  console.log("scroll")
}

function onKeyUp(event){
  if(event.key == "ArrowUp" || event.key == "ArrowDown"){
     onScroll(event);
  }
}
```

Please note browser support for this event from the MDN page and test appropriately according to your needs.

Updated pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVRxed?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect. But how can I have the event only triggered once per each "scroll", like in onscroll.

Comment: Great, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

By definition, no scroll events will get fired if nothing can be scrolled.